# How to retrieve function duration information within code?

Tags: c

This is more of a curiosity question than anything else but say a function takes 0.2434634 seconds to finish doing its thing is there a way I can access this information and use it within my code?

Comment: You could *time it*, there's no other standard way to get the execution time of a function. But outside of calculating frame-rates and other game- and frame-rate related uses (or statistics) what it should be used for I don't know.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It may be used to determine if it worth the effort to optimise a given function.

Comment: But are you asking for specific tools, libraries, methods? Maybe, in this case, you also need to say what's your ultimate goal.

Comment: About the simplest way is to do something like `double t1 = 0.0, t2 = 0.0; t1 = clock(); /* call your function */ t2 = clock();` Then you can `printf ("function X (%lf sec)\n", (t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is there a more accurate clock? like nanoclock() or something

Comment: @Theo Walton there is no nedd. Run your function many times with different data. You can flush the uP || uC cache if your micro has machine code instructions for it.

Comment: @TheoWalton, yes there are more accurate clocks available. Those shown in the answer would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the ealpsed time by storing time point **before** function call and subtract it from time point **after** function call. With high accuracy on POSIX systems this can be achieved by [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void foo() {
    sleep(1);
}

double to_milli(struct timespec* ts) {
    return (1.0e3 * ts->tv_sec) + (1.0e-6 * ts->tv_nsec);
}

int main() {
    struct timespec tp_begin, tp_end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp_begin);
    foo(); /* call the desired function */
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp_end);

    printf("Elapsed time: %.5f ms\n", to_milli(&tp_end) - to_milli(&tp_begin));
    return 0;
}
```